# Show only valid rows in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, binding, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I have a DataTable with some rows. Each row is an object and columns are its attributes. Lets say that I have 6 attributes:

Person (FirstName, SecondName, Address, Phone, Email, Valid)

I want to bind this table to DataGridView with DataView. I don't want to show last attribute Valid in the DGW because this is not information for user. Attribute valid is Bolean and if it is True, this object is shown it the DGW but if it is False it is not shown in DGW.

How can I show only valid objects if a datasource is binded to DGW with DataView? Thanks!

Comment: Datagridview column has visible property .. you should use it

Comment: Change your SQL statement to SELECT the columns you DO want to show and only select those WHERE Valid is true.